# How can I connect a turtle object with an instance of a class in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am new to python and I am trying to creat a simple race game using turtle library.

I have a Car class and a world class.  in the world class I want to create an instance of the car.

Here is the class Car

```
class Car():
def __init__ (self, brand, acceleration, maxSpeed):
    self.brand = brand
    self.acceleration = acceleration
    self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
    print(f'{self.brand} has an acceleration of {self.acceleration} and a max speed of {self.maxSpeed}\n')
```

and here is the class World.   it's not completed yet!
I was hoping that this would have fix my problem but it didn't ->
car1 = Car ('bmw', 2.5, 200)

car1 = tr.Turtle()

```
class World:
def __init__(self):
    self.screen = tr.Screen ()
    self.screen.listen ()
    self.screen.onkey (self.forward, 'a')
    self.screen.onkey (self.backward, 'z')
    self.time = tm.time ()

car1 = Car ('bmw', 2.5, 200)
car1 = tr.Turtle()

def forward (self):
    self.carOne.fd(45)        
    print ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
    
def backward (self):
    self.carOne.back(45)
    print ('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz')

def run (self):
    while True:                 # Main real-time simulation loop
        # BEGIN mandatory statements
        self.oldTime = self.time
        self.newTime = tm.time ()  # The only place where the realtime clock is repeatedly queried
        self.deltaTime = self.newTime - self.oldTime
        # END mandatory statements
        
        # ... other code, using objects that are in the world, like a racetrack and cars
        # baan = self.Track(selfO.deltaTime)


        # print (self.deltaTime)
        self.screen.update ()
        tm.sleep (0.02)         # Needed to free up processor for other tasks like I/O

world = World ()
world.run ()
```

**My question is how do I create a turtle object which is connected to the instans of the Car class?**

forexample in the constructor of car I give it a name and a speed and acceleration -> which is calculated in a method.

so what I want is that the turtle object gets the same parameters as the car instance.  you can also say I want the turtle object to be the instance of the car.

the idea is to add more cars later.

Is that possible? if not is there anyother way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line redefines `car1` from a `Car` class object to a `tr.Turtle()` object. It won't have any of the characteristics you defined previously.

```
car1 = Car ('bmw', 2.5, 200)
car1 = tr.Turtle()
```

What might work would be to instantiate a `tr.Turtle()` inside the `Car` constructor. This might look like

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, type, num1, num2):
        self.type = type
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self.turtleBoi = tr.Turtle()
car1 = Car('bmw', 2.5, 200)
car1.turtleBoi.forward(15)
```